# Wordpress Plugin Restrict Access To Pages For People Who Have Bought A Product

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

Do you know what is the best plugin that provides restricted access to posts, pages, bbPress forums for users that have purchased your WooCommerce products. I build my website with Wordpress.

I want to have a hidden page for my visitors that says : "You should buy this product to get access to the page!" And when a visitor buys the product he will get access to the page.

Do you know a wordpress plugin that will do the job. Also, I am using Thrive Content Builder and I am afraid that the plugin might interfere with Thrive.

Please, help!

Comment: Please note that this is off topic, as questions asking for recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I am not asking for recommendation. I am asking how to do it in Wordpress and I guess i have to use a wordpress plugin. But if you know any other way i will appreciate you share your knowledge here. Thanks.

Comment: Please review the link in my previous comment. "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic*". If you are looking for help in writing the code, please note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to *research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself* before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of premium access plugins for WordPress, and I've no specific reasons to recommend one over the other. However, you need a little bit of custom coding to achieve the specific results, as you are asking to buy a specific product instead of premium access.

Here is one approach:

1. Hook into WooCommerce's `woocommerce_thankyou` hook. You can do it
   like this: `add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou',
   'custom_woocommerce_thankyou_action', 10, 1 );`
2. Obtain the customer id and check if the customer is already a premium member? Exit, if true.
3. Now, iterate through all the items in the order.
4. If the product id matches with the specified product, change the user's membership type to *premium member*.

This approach should suffice for all generic cases. Share more details if you are having trouble with anything specific.